# htaccess - make public directory accessible

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Yes, this has been asked here a lot, none of the solutions provided worked for me.

**folder structure**

```
/
+-- _projects
|   +-- includes
|   |   |-- main.class.php
|   +-- scripts
|   |   |-- saveitems.php
|   +-- view
|   |   |-- layout.php
|   |-- index.php
|   |-- .htaccess
|     
+-- _pub
|   +-- img
|   |   |-- webicon_facebook.png
|   |   |-- webicon_twitter.png
|
+-- view
+-- includes
|-- index.php
|-- .htaccess
```

**.htaccess file in root:**

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/(.+)$ index.php?page=$1&item=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**The mission:**
Enable browsers to access any folder or file in **_pub**

**What I've tried:**

- Using a .htaccess file with `Satisfy Any` `Allow from all` in
  **_pub**
- Disabling the RewriteEngine inside the **_pub** folder
- Change the root htaccess file to include something like `RewriteRule ^_pub/$ _pub/ [L]` right below `RewriteBase \`

The curious thing is that when browsing to **_projects** the index file within that folder is accessed and the website from it loads perfectly.
But when accessing **_pub** (without index file) I get a 403 error from the host.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something in the root htaccess file that would allow direct access to folders and files in **_pub**, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Are you trying to get Apache to list the contents of the directory? As in list files and folders within?

Comment: Yes I am trying to get Apache to list the contents of **_pub**, as I wish to use images inside **_pub/img** to be used on other sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your root .htaccess like this:

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/_pub/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/(.+)$ index.php?page=$1&item=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: anubhava, seeing how your reputation is quite high, I trust that you posted the right answer and it should work. However, it doesn't and I'm starting to believe that my host is responsible. I'm thinking that whenever a folder doesn't contain an index file, the host will generate a 403 page.
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: So you are still getting 403 for any `/_pub/something` URI?

Answer (score 0):

If directory indexing is your intent then you shouldn't use `Options -Indexes` which disables directory indexing, you should use `Options +Indexes`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to treat `_pub` as an exception: You don't want the normal rules to apply, and you would like to allow direct access to all files in `_pub` without rewriting. There are several ways to do this without creating more `.htaccess` rules in `_pub`.

One way is to change the rules you already have in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` by adding a negative lookahead:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!_pub)([a-z]+)\/(.+)$ index.php?page=$1&item=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(?!_pub)([a-z]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Try that, without changing the RewriteConds you showed in your question.

Comment: I had good hopes for this, adding `(?!_pub)`. But didn't work.

Comment: Mmm... Maybe an expert like @anubhava comes along and finds the solution. :)